# What is the interpretation of 'measurable function' here?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-integrals

On the topic of stochastic integration we have the following.

*For Brownian motion $W$ and square-integrable, measurable function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one can define a random variable*

\begin{align}
Z = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dW_t
\end{align}

*and this random variable is then such that it follows a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)^2dt$.*

Now my question is on the requirement that the function be measurable. I followed a course treating parts of measure theory. But, I believe I was told that a function can be measurable with respect to a sigma algebra (sigma field). However often I see requirements like the one above, without any mention of a sigma algebra. Can somebody maybe clarify this for me? Is there some convention ?

Comment: Is there some convention ? Don't know, if thre'e are *official* ones, but $\mathbb{R}$ has a measure via closed intervals, such that $a<b\;\;\mu([a,b]:=a-b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "measurable" is used for a function on a real interval without mention of a $\sigma$-algebra, Lebesgue measurable is generally meant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Difficult to see two different answers. But I guess my question kind of elicits that. I will have to go with superiority here.

Comment: @Robert Israel. In probability theory, one uses Borel measurable and not Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to equip $\mathbb R$ and its subsets with a $\sigma$-algebra is to take the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open subsets. This is usually implied if we call a function $f:A\to\mathbb R$, $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ measurable.

There are also other ways to equip it with a $\sigma$-algebra, like the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, or any other $\sigma$-algebra, really. But if it isn't mentioned, then it's the Borel one.